# XDocument reading child elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've just started using Linq to XML with C#. I have an XML file containing information about books.

The XML file has this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I've managed to write code that lets me get a list of the authors and a list of books from the XML file:

```
public List<string> GetBooks()
{
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(XMLFileLocation);

    var query = from t in document.Descendants("title")
                select t.Value;

    return query.ToList<string>();
}
```

However, I don't know how to proceed with making a method that would let me get information about a specific book. For example:

```
GetBookAuthor("MyBook");
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stick with XDocument, this is a simple way to get an author by book name:

```
public static string GetBookAuthor(XDocument xDoc, string title)
{
    return xDoc.Root
        .Elements("book")
        .First(b => b.Element("title").Value == title)
        .Element("author")
        .Value;
}
```

**However I'd suggest object oriented approach:**

Why not create a Book class with Author and Title properties, then you don't need a GetBookAuthor method?

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    // other Book properties ...
}
```

To get a list of Book objects:

```
public static List<Book> GetBooks()
{
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);

    var query = from t in document.Root.Elements("book")
                select new Book()
                {
                    Author = t.Element("author").Value,
                    Title = t.Element("title").Value
                };

    return query.ToList();
}
```

You can then return a Book object by its name:

```
public static Book GetBook(List<Book> bookList, string title)
{
    return bookList.First(b => b.Title == title);
}
```

And access the Author property:

```
var bookList = GetBooks()
var author = GetBook(bookList, "MyBook").Author;
```

Now, if author was more complex element, you can create an Author class as well, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search by `ID`:

```
var author = document.Descendans("book")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("id") == id)
   .Select(x => (string)x.Element("author"))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want to search by `Title`:

```
var author = document.Descendans("book")
   .Where(x => (string)x.Element("title") == title)
   .Select(x => (string)x.Element("author"))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then check for null and return the author name:

```
if(author != null)
   return author;
```